# numpy determine mean diff between arguments

Tags: numpy, scipy

Is there any ready made function to determine the average of differences between arguments of a sorted list?

for example, here is my manual try:

```
import numpy as np
rand_A = np.random.rand_integers(0, 99, 10)
np.sort(rand_A)
array([ 3,  8, 26, 34, 35, 37, 65, 82, 89, 94])

def mean_period(data):
    diffe = 0
    for ind in range(data.shape[0] - 1)
        diffe += data[ind + 1] - data[ind]
    return (diffe / (data.shape[0] - 1))

mean_period(np.sort(rand_A))
10
```

Basically I need this function to determine the frequency value of a sinus like signal which will be used as initial guess parameter for the scipy.leastsq function to fit it.
I need the fastest routine. I'm afraid my try will be a big load.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see. If I understood your question correctly, we are talking about zero-crossings in frequency detector. You have the time stamps of the zero-crossings in a list (which is then sorted by necessity) and want to calculate the average difference of items in a list.

While `unutbu`'s answer is correct and very Numpyish, I would like to suggest a brief look into the maths. Average of difference of consecutive elements is:

```
{ (s_1 - s_0) + (s_2 - s_1) + (s_3 - s_2) + ... + (s_n - s_(n-1)) } / n
```

There seem to be quite many terms cancelling out. What is left is:

```
(s_n - s_0) / n
```

So, the function above becomes:

```
def mean_period(data):
    return 1. * (data[-1] - data[0]) / (len(data) - 1)
```

If we do some benchmarks with sorted data, then:

```
rand_A = np.random.randint(0,99999999,10000000)
sort_A = np.sort(rand_A)

% timeit np.diff(sort_A).mean()     # 37.7 ms
% timeit mean_period(sort_A)        # 0.98 ms
```

(The latter one is essentially O(1) plus it suffers from the slight function call overhead).

If the data is not sorted, then we will have to find the largest and smallest values:

```
def mean_period_unsorted(data):
    smallest = np.min(data)
    largest = np.max(data)
    return 1. * (largest - smallest) / (len(data) - 1)
```

So maybe this time a bit of maths helps :)
And now the benchmarks

```
% timeit np.diff(np.sort(rand_A)).mean()   # 733 ms
% timeit mean_period_unsorted(rand_A)      # 17.9 ms
```

Comment: it's not zero crossings; here my points correspond to maxima. zero crossings would complicate things as there are two/period. Right, the mathematical simplification obviously make things faster here. But in fact, as I'm working on noisy experimental data, I need another mean. Probably I will use fourier transform.

Comment: @user1850133: Frequency detection is surprisingly complicated in noisy environment. Zero-cross with hysteresis and dead-time windowing is one possibility, but even then other frequency components will cause problems. Fourier transform is a good candidate, as it has been quite thoroughly optimized, but there are at least two things you'll need to think of: windowing and interpolation of the frequency peak. Also, if your frequency is changing even a bit, you may need to first find the frequency roughly with F-transform, then bandpass-filter it, and then use zero-crossings or equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

```
np.diff(np.sort(rand_A)).mean()
```

is almost equivalent to `mean_period(np.sort(rand_A))`, but should be faster since it uses NumPy method calls instead of a Python loop.

I say "almost equivalent" because there is one difference: `mean_period` always returns an int, since `diffe` is a `numpy.int32` and the return value is the result of dividing this `int32` by an `int`, (`data.shape[0]-1`).

In contrast, `np.diff(np.sort(rand_A)).mean()` returns a Numpy `float64`.

---

Edit: For small arrays (such as the one you posted in your question), the Python loop is faster:

```
In [84]: %timeit mean_period(np.sort(rand_A))
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.29 µs per loop

In [85]: %timeit np.diff(np.sort(rand_A)).mean()
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.5 µs per loop
```

but for large arrays, such as a million-element array,

```
rand_A = np.random.random_integers(0, 99, 10**6)
```

using NumPy's `mean` and `diff` methods is much faster:

```
In [87]: %timeit mean_period(np.sort(rand_A))
1 loops, best of 3: 442 ms per loop

In [88]: %timeit np.diff(np.sort(rand_A)).mean()
10 loops, best of 3: 48.8 ms per loop
```

---

See also:

- [numpy.diff](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)
- [numpy.mean](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html)